# How to extract certain values from one column based on restrictions fulfilled in another column?

Tags: r, rows

I am trying to construct a code in r that will return values from certain rows in one column based on values from rows in a different column.

More specific I have the following dataset (`BTM`):

```
Date       CompanyName   MarketValue  BookValue    BookToMarket
31.12.87   Bure Equity   2182000      2260267      
31.01.88   Bure Equity   2102000      1950267
29.02.88   Bure Equity   2182000      2550267
...
31.07.88   Bure Equity   2022000      2980267  BookValue Des87/MarketValueJuly88
31.08.88   Bure Equity   2162000      2650267
30.09.88   Bure Equity   2272000      2390267  BookValue Des87/MarketValueSept88
31.10.88   Bure Equity   2122000      2650267
30.11.88   Bure Equity   2382000      2350267
31.12.88
31.12.87   H&M           2182000      2650267
31.01.88   H&M           2102000      2650267
29.02.88   H&M           2182000      2650267
```

(This is only a small excerpt from the total dataset; I have about 1000 companies and 30 years of monthly data for each company)

I need to calculate the Book-to-Market value for each company within each date. However, I need to use the book-value from december 1987 when calculating the book-to-market values from july 1988 until june 1989. This means that I need to get R to understand that when calculating book-to-market values in the period july 1988 - june 1989; R need to use the book-value from desember 1987 while using the market value in the given month.

In other words I need to code the following: Get the book-value for "Bure Equity" IF it corresponds to the date 31.12.87. Then divide this book-value on the market value for "Bure Equity" from july 88 and until june 89.
(This need to be coded so it works for each company and for the period 1987-2016).

In order to do this I tried to type the following in r:

```
BTM$"Book to Market" <- ((BTM$"Book Value" | "Date"=="1987-12")/BTM$"Market Value")
```

This gives me some values, but as expected not the right ones.

Ideally I want a formula that can give me the value from the "Book value"-column IF it corresponds to December 87, December 88, December 89 etc. in the "Date" column.

Further I then need R to divide the chosen book-values on the different market values in the following months july 88-june89, july 89 - june 90 etc.

It is also important that R separates the Companies from each other. For example, I need R to understand that it can only divide the book value of H&M in december 97 on the market value in july 88 for H&M (and not for example Bure Equity).

Does anyone have an idea on how I can get this done?

I appreciate any tips I can get.

Comment: I think you can use dplyr to achieve this. Can you post a reproducible example of your data so we can play around? `dput(head(BTM))` should work.

Comment: In your example, all your `BookValue`'s are the same, can you provide data where you have different `BookValue`'s?

Comment: I have now changed the BookValue's :)

Comment: And is it ok if I remove the empty lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(CompanyName) %>%
  filter(month(Date) == 12) %>%
  inner_join(df, by = "CompanyName") %>%
  select(Date = Date.y, CompanyName, MarketValue = MarketValue.y, BookValue = BookValue.x) %>%
  mutate(BookToMarket = BookValue/MarketValue,
         Date = dmy(Date))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   CompanyName [3]
         Date CompanyName MarketValue BookValue BookToMarket
       <date>      <fctr>       <int>     <int>        <dbl>
 1 1987-12-31  BureEquity     2182000   2260267    1.0358694
 2 1988-01-31  BureEquity     2102000   2260267    1.0752935
 3 1988-02-29  BureEquity     2182000   2260267    1.0358694
 4 1988-07-31  BureEquity     2022000   2260267    1.1178373
 5 1988-08-31  BureEquity     2162000   2260267    1.0454519
 6 1988-09-30  BureEquity     2272000   2260267    0.9948358
 7 1988-10-31  BureEquity     2122000   2260267    1.0651588
 8 1988-11-30  BureEquity     2382000   2260267    0.9488946
 9 1988-12-31                      NA        NA           NA
10 1987-12-31         H&M     2182000   2650267    1.2146045
11 1988-01-31         H&M     2102000   2650267    1.2608311
12 1988-02-29         H&M     2182000   2650267    1.2146045
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "Date       CompanyName   MarketValue  BookValue   
                31.12.87   BureEquity   2182000      2260267      
                31.01.88   BureEquity   2102000      1950267
                29.02.88   BureEquity   2182000      2550267
                31.07.88   BureEquity   2022000      2980267  
                31.08.88   BureEquity   2162000      2650267
                30.09.88   BureEquity   2272000      2390267  
                31.10.88   BureEquity   2122000      2650267
                30.11.88   BureEquity   2382000      2350267
                31.12.88
                31.12.87   H&M           2182000      2650267
                31.01.88   H&M           2102000      2650267
                29.02.88   H&M           2182000      2650267", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer! However, it does not seem to work:

> BTM %>%
+   mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
+   group_by("Company Name") %>%
+   filter(month(Date) == 12) %>%
+   inner_join(BTM, by = "Company Name") %>%
+   select(Date = Date.y, "Company Name", "Market Value" = MarketValue.y, "Book Value" = BookValue.x) %>%
+ mutate(BookToMarket = "Book Value"/"Market Value",
+          Date = dmy(Date))
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : 
  object 'MarketValue.y' not found
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: I needed to add a space between BookValue and MarketValue and so on, as the columns are called Book Value, Market Value and so on. This was the only change I made to your code (plus replaced df With BTM given that BTM is the name of my dataframe), however, I always get an error message. Do you maybe know what the problem might be?

Comment: This is the code I typed in: 

BTM %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
  group_by("Company Name") %>%
  filter(month(Date) == 12) %>%
  inner_join(BTM, by = "Company Name") %>%
  select(Date = Date.y, "Company Name", "Market Value" = MarketValue.y, "Book Value" = BookValue.x) %>%
  mutate(BookToMarket = "Book Value"/"Market Value",
         Date = dmy(Date))

Comment: @Marthe Well, this problem might be related to the data you actually have. Instead of copy and pasting the table, copy and paste the output of `dput(BTM)` into your question. This preserves the data types for each column. If `BTM` is too large, make a subset of it then `duput(subset)`. Side note, when troubleshooting, you can go from the top of the pipe and incrementally add a new pipe and see if you get an error. This way you know exactly which step went wrong.